# VSCode and git: how to use git for more than one project?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, workspace

In VSCode, I have two folders open in a workspace each belonging to two git projects. How do I switch focus between the two folders so I can conveniently use VSC's git features on both folders?

Answer (score 1):

When you show the Source Control tab (click the button on the left in the screenshot), VS Code shows you all the git repos for your open folders:

[image]

Here I have two repos (hellocli3 and KrakenRepo).

By clicking the `>` to expand the repo you want, you then get to use VS Code's git features for that repo. The features can be found by hovering over the icons to the right of the repo name:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't with VS Code fluently. But easily can with [Atom](https://atom.io/) or [Theia](https://theia-ide.org/).
Theia is VS Code fork by Eclipse foundation. It's pretty the same as VS Code with minor changes. One of the changes is the ability to select working repo with a dropdown menu, like in Atom.

As one of VS Code contributes says, VS Code Git working design is a feature, so very unlikely sometimes it will be changed.

You can use multi-root workspace, but you still need to manually change Git repo.

While using multi-root project (File -> Open -> select first project, then select other projects with File -> Open -> Add Folder to Workspace), open SCM tab, there are a few ways to work with different repos:

#### Temporary disable repositories

While working with large amount of git repositories, you can temporary remove extra from SCM sidebar repo with `…`on `Source Control` tab -> Views & Sort -> Repositories -> uncheck repos you don't need this time.
[Disable repository screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOzWf.png)

#### Choose working repo with `Source Control Repositories` tab.

Firstly, enable `Source Control Repositories` in SCM tab.

Right mouse click on SCM tab -> Repositories
There you can select one of more active repos.
[Select active repositories screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9T4AS.png)

#### Fold end expand

You can just fold and expand active/non-active repos as [Reg Edit](https://superuser.com/a/1568697/1656108) answered. But it will be awkward with a lot of repos.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1100723)